# mono-test-install fails with a System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, linux, mono

I'm on debian (Linux 5.7.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.7.6-1 (2020-06-24) x86_64 GNU/Linux) and I installed the Mono Framework recently (`sudo apt-get install mono-devel`).

`mono --version` gives me

```
Mono JIT compiler version 6.8.0.105 (Debian 6.8.0.105+dfsg-3 Wed Apr  8 15:33:36 UTC 2020)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           __thread
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notifications: epoll
    Architecture:  amd64
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug 
    Interpreter:   yes
    LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
    Suspend:       hybrid
    GC:            sgen (concurrent by default)
```

Then, I tried running `mono-test-install`:

```
Active Mono: /usr/bin/mono
Other Mono executables: /bin/mono 

You have a working System.Drawing setup

Unhandled Exception:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at Program.Main () [0x00016] in <70d3c907c7f1453aa373f2b3e2a3a38a>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at Program.Main () [0x00016] in <70d3c907c7f1453aa373f2b3e2a3a38a>:0
```

In the generated source file, there is following code:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;

class Program {

    public static void Main()
    {
        object watcher = new FileSystemWatcher()
            .GetType ()
            .GetField ("watcher", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
            .GetValue (null); //Here it fails
        
        Console.WriteLine ("Your file system watcher is: {0}",
                   watcher != null
                   ? watcher.GetType ().FullName
                   : "unknown");
    }
}
```

Should I be concerned?

Comment: I've having the same issue on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Probably an outdated test program. I've the same error when running mono-test-install,  but all my FileSystemWatcher  works fine in my programs. So i'd say not a source of worry.